# Форматирование Excel на Go. Как сделать "Итоги в строках под данными"?

Tags: xml, golang, xlsx

При настройке уровня строки (группировка), можно выбрать направление, в котором будут сгруппированы линии, как это сделать с помощью Go? Сейчас использую библиотеку tealeg/xlsx

Как это выглядит при использовании VBA в Excel:

```
ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove
```

В XML файле рабочего листа эта настройка выглядит как

```
<outlinePr summaryBelow="0"/>
```

[Эта же настройка просто в Excel (Данные - Структура - Расположение итоговых данных)](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52b5f43ee4b02301e647b446/t/58b200399f7456906a38d0e8/1488062729462/Steps+to+Change+Settings+for+Outline+Groups+in+Excel)

Не нашла решения в  tealeg/xlsx ([что есть для работы с XML](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx/blob/master/xmlWorksheet.go)) и слишком мало знаю Go, чтобы самой написать функцию.
Help me...

Comment: Не работал много с XLSX, но вот этот пакет похоже имеет что-то подобное: https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize.